# Can I prevent CSS from applying to a particular element?

Tags: jquery, css

I guess this is sort of an odd question... and I don't even know if it's a good idea.  Can I create an element and say, "I don't care what any of the stylesheets that came before said, here is how I want it styled?"

So just as an example, say I have a stylesheet that says:

```
button {
   /* whole bunch of stuff here, not even sure what all */
}

.someClass button {
   /* and some other crap here*/
}

.anotherClass button {
  /* and more here */
}
```

And then I want to write some Javascript that will do something like this:

```
function insertConstantButton(elemId) {
    var unchangeableButton = $('<button/>');
    unchangeableButton.css('whatIReallyWant', 'etc');
    $("#" + elemId).append(unchangeableButton);
    andNowIMagicallyStopCSSFromApplyingTo(unchangeableButton);
}
```

Like I say, maybe this is even a bad idea... just wondering... I have some code creating this button, and it looks great, but then suddenly I have it appearing under a different class of container than it normally appears and (surprise) it looks all different.  Which I don't want.  heh.

Update: Yeah, kinda knew this was a bad idea, just was wondering if it was possible.  I'm not surprised it isn't, since it would kinda, uh, break CSS :)

To the person who wanted the general problem rather than an assumed solution:  I have some code that will add consistent-looking scroll buttons in exactly the way the UI team wants them to look.  I am trying to put them in a modal dialog now, and the modal dialog has a bunch of stuff in the stylesheet like ".ourCompanyPopup button { stuffIDontWantOnMyScrollbars; }"  Overriding each one is going to be a PITA.

I could probably change the stylesheet to something like ".ourCompanyPopup button:not(.myPreciousScrollButtons)"...  That will get-er-done, but might be just as much of a maintainability nightmare as anything else.  Hmmm...

Comment: Nope, the css will apply to it regardless unless you override each thing that the css does.

Comment: I’m sure there are more than existing questions on this, but they can be hard to find (difficult to select keywords). Anyway, the answer is “No”, and you should formulate a question that describes the original problem, not an assumed solution, which is a dead end.

Comment: Create a class that overrides all CSS using `!important` for each item.

Comment: Please don't use `!important` for each item. I'm the guy who has to maintain that code and I'll be very cross with you. Simply put, you're approaching the problem wrong. Do it a different way.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda was leaning towards Nathan's answer anyway :) But was just curious.

Comment: Oh, and if it helps Nathan sleep better at night... I don't use !important, ever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: no.

CSS will be applied anyway. What you can do is the following:

- overwrite the unwanted CSS
- make the unwanted css so specific that your button is not included

I would recommend this:

**jQuery**

```
function insertConstantButton(elemId) {
        var unchangeableButton = $('<button class="dontchange" />');
        unchangeableButton.css('whatIReallyWant', 'etc');
        $("#" + elemId).append(unchangeableButton);
    }
```

**CSS**

```
button:not(.dontchange) {
   /* whole bunch of stuff here, not even sure what all */
}

.someClass button:not(.dontchange) {
   /* and some other crap here*/
}

.anotherClass button:not(.dontchange) {
  /* and more here */
}
```

If that is not elegant enough, give the button an ID and style it in the stylesheet.
**jQuery**

```
function insertConstantButton(elemId) {
        var unchangeableButton = $('<button id="dontchange" />');
        $("#" + elemId).append(unchangeableButton);
    }
```

**CSS**

```
button#dontchange {
    /* your CSS */
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my update, this is probably the quickest way to do what I want... I'm just debating whether it will be a maintainability nightmare or not.  Might do it anyway, what with deadlines and all (oops, did I say that aloud?)

Comment: On further reflection, I think this is actually okay.  It means the popup styling now has to be aware it might have scroll buttons in it.  But the stylesheet reads very naturally now:  "Any buttons inside a popup get this styling, EXCEPT scroll buttons".  Fair 'nuff.

Answer (score 3):

use an ID. One ID will override 15 million classes.

Comment: The point is that the button could appear as a descendant of different classes, and short of over-specifying the CSS for EVERY possible thing that could be overriden, an ID doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: The point of the ID is that it doesn't matter where or how many descendants of CLASSES there are, the rule set for an ID will override it. Unless you're dealing with some CMS that injects a lot of junk and that junk includes an ID, just make a function that creates a button with an ID and address the ID in the css stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah, you're not really getting the point.  What you're suggesting here is essentially the same as the guy who said, "Override everything with !important".

Comment: I could ask the same question without using classes at all.  Replace every "." in the original question with a "#", and you'd have the same problem.

Comment: The reason !important is never a good idea is because of maintenance. One would have to go back to EVERY !important style and change it..not the point of css. Change ONE ID and it's done. I guess I don't understand why you would be adding a class to a dynamic element that needs to be styled on its own. Don't add a class to the new button at all. Perhaps it's your selectors you're not getting. Just because 'button' is in the selector doesn't mean every button will be selected. button.myclass is different from 'button myclass' as is #myButton. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `!important` modifier, but you need to mark every single style you don't want to be overwritten as `!important`:

```
button {
  background-color: red;
}

.what-i-really-want {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

function insertConstantButton(elemId) {
  var unchangeableButton = $('<button/>');
  unchangeableButton.addClass('what-i-really-want');
  $("#" + elemId).append(unchangeableButton);
  andNowIMagicallyStopCSSFromApplyingTo(unchangeableButton);
}
```

Comment: The downvote might be because your jQuery function is not completely needed and because it is too much of a hassle to overwrite every single property with an `!important` statement.