# using HTML's details/summary in shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

How can I restore the "arrow" style in HTML's details/summary collapsible section?

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(tags$details(tags$summary("Collapsible"), "This content is inside"))
writeLines(capture.output(ui), "~/tmp/qq.html")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

Comparing the raw HTML (in `"qq.html"`) on the left with the shiny rendering on the right,

[image: side-by-side, raw HTML on the left, shiny on the right]

I can't get the basic `style=` theming to work, such as

```r
tags$summary("Collapsible", style = "list-style-type: disc;")
```

I know that `shiny` does a lot of styling in the background, but I feel like I'm missing something fairly basic here.

(In case it matters, this is on ubuntu 23.10 running firefox-122, though it's the same in chrome-120.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style provided by your browser is overwritten by bootstrap (bootstrap-3.4.1/css/less/normalize.less).
From Chromes DevTools:

[image: result]

Accordingly, another option is to apply the default again:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(tags$details(tags$summary("Collapsible", style = "display: list-item;"), "This content is inside"))
writeLines(capture.output(ui), "qq.html")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

In this situation [there is no other way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15932542/9841389) to prevent the style from being applied (apart from modifying the according dependencies).

Comment: Variation on a theme (of overwriting `display:`), I like it. Thanks! I had seen the linked answer you provided and was still trying to work through the options.

Comment: Sure, not a big difference but a little [more explicit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) than using `revert` (as rolling back depends on the context)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one way, using the special `revert` CSS keyword.

```r
tags$details(
  tags$summary("Collapsible", style = "display:revert;"),
               "This content is inside")
)
```